# Jasmine test not working, gets undefined when expecting spy

Tags: jasmine, jasmine2.0

I'm trying to use a spy to watch when a functino call is made.  I can't get it to work with my code though.

My test

```
            it("calls the totalBogof() function", function() {
                spyOn(basket(), "totalBogof");
                basket().total();
                expect(basket.totalBogof).toHaveBeenCalled();
            });
```

The code I'm trying to test:

```
basket.prototype = {
    total: function(){
       var total=0.00;
       for(var i=0; i<shoppingBasket.length; i++){
            total += shoppingBasket[i].price;  
        }
         $('#total').html('total = '+currency+total.toFixed(2));
         this.totalBogof(total);
    },
    totalBogof: function(total){
         totalMinBOGOF = total - this.calcBOGOF();
         $('#total-bogof').html('Total - BOGOF = ' + currency + totalMinBOGOF.toFixed(2));
         this.totalPercentageDiscount(totalMinBOGOF, 10);
    },
}
```

The error I'm getting is this:

```
5 specs, 1 failureSpec List | Failures
shoppingBasket calls the totalBogof() function
Error: Expected a spy, but got undefined.
Error: Expected a spy, but got undefined.
 at compare     (https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jasmine/2.4.1/jasmine.js:3083:17)
 at Expectation.toHaveBeenCalled     (https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jasmine/2.4.1/jasmine.js:1480:35)
 at Object.<anonymous> (file:///C:/Users/G/shoppingbasket-jasmine/shopping-basket.js:56:47)
 at attemptSync     (https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jasmine/2.4.1/jasmine.js:1886:24)
 at QueueRunner.run     (https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jasmine/2.4.1/jasmine.js:1874:9)
 at QueueRunner.execute (https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jasmine/2.4.1/jasmine.js:1859:10)
 at Spec.queueRunnerFactory (https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jasmine/2.4.1/jasmine.js:697:35)
 at Spec.execute (https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jasmine/2.4.1/jasmine.js:359:10)
 at Object.fn (https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jasmine/2.4.1/jasmine.js:2479:37)
 at attemptAsync (https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jasmine/2.4.1/jasmine.js:1916:24)
```

Any ideas what I need to do to fix this?

Answer (score 3):

Did you try this? Look at the Spies [documentation](https://jasmine.github.io/2.0/introduction.html#section-Spies)

```
it("calls the totalBogof() function", function() {
   spyOn(basket, "totalBogof");
   basket.total();
   expect(basket.totalBogof).toHaveBeenCalled();
});
```